# php uploading to bitbucket without installing git on server

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

Is there anyway I can upload some new files into my **bitbucket repo** without installing GIT into my server?

I am trying to use PHP (on a shared hosting Linux server) to upload files `git add` into a shared repo.

A friend suggested me that I use this but that also needs an installation
of git on the server:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:your_account/your_repo.git
```

Comment: I didn't understand do you have two remotes: your own and bitbucket?

Comment: @zaratustra yes you are right, mine is a shared hosting and I need to upload into bitbucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add a new remote that points at bitbucket (you have this command already):

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:your_account/your_repo.git
```

Then you need to push all your branches (You named the bitbucket remote `origin` so):

```
git push --all origin
```

But if you want to push some of them you need to push them individually:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Many thanks @zaratustra but I am not getting permission to install git and run this command on a shared hosting.